# proxy_pass requests only if the localhost file exists

Tags: nginx

```
server {
        listen       9991;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            if ( -e http://localhost:8001/assets/plugin-web-layout5/plugin-web-layout5\.js ) {
                rewrite ^/assets/plugin-web-layout5/plugin-web-layout5 http://localhost:8001/assets/plugin-web-layout5/plugin-web-layout5.js;
            }
           
            proxy_pass http://xxxx.cn/web/;
        }


        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://xxxx.cn/api;
        }
    }
```

How to judge the existence of the local localhost file? Access the local file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

One can only check existence of files that are available via the local file system. One can not check existence of remote files.

You need to handle the checking on the server that runs at `localhost:8001`.